# RTE is not working online

Tags: php, rich-text-editor

I've developed a dynamic site where I've used rich text editor. When I change font color, size and highlight the text, enter url link into content, it perfectly works in my local server but when I upload my site, these functions didn't work online. I don't know where has problem occurred. Is there anyone genius who could help me to sort out this problem? Thanks in advance.

Since I couldn't post any new questions, I'm editing my old question coz I don't have any choice.

I'm just praying that if anyone genius who would solve my problem.

*** My RTE javascript goes like this***

```
var isRichText = false;
var rng;
var currentRTE;
var allRTEs = "";
var isIE;
var isGecko;
var isSafari;
var isKonqueror;
var imagesPath;
var includesPath;
var cssFile;
function initRTE(imgPath, incPath, css) {
//set browser vars
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
isIE = ((ua.indexOf("msie") != -1) && (ua.indexOf("opera") == -1) && (ua.indexOf("webtv") == -1)); 
isGecko = (ua.indexOf("gecko") != -1);
isSafari = (ua.indexOf("safari") != -1);
isKonqueror = (ua.indexOf("konqueror") != -1);

//check to see if designMode mode is available
if (document.getElementById && document.designMode && !isSafari && !isKonqueror) {
    isRichText = true;
}

if (isIE) {
    document.onmouseover = raiseButton;
    document.onmouseout  = normalButton;
    document.onmousedown = lowerButton;
    document.onmouseup   = raiseButton;
}

//set paths vars
imagesPath = imgPath;
includesPath = incPath;
cssFile = css;

if (isRichText) document.writeln('<style type="text/css">@import "' + includesPath + 'rte.css";</style>');

//for testing standard textarea, uncomment the following line
//isRichText = false;
}

function writeRichText(rte, html, width, height, buttons, readOnly) {
if (isRichText) {
    if (allRTEs.length > 0) allRTEs += ";";
    allRTEs += rte;

    if (readOnly) buttons = false;

    //adjust minimum table widths
    if (isIE) {
        if (buttons && (width < 800)) width = 650;
        var tablewidth = width;
    } else {
        if (buttons && (width < 800)) width = 650;
        var tablewidth = width + 4;
    }

    document.writeln('<div class="rteDiv">');
    if (buttons == true) 
{
document.writeln('<table class="rteBack" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 id="Buttons1_' + rte + '" width="' + tablewidth + '">');
document.writeln('  <tr>');
document.writeln('      <td>');
document.writeln('          <select id="formatblock_' + rte + '" onchange="selectFont(\'' + rte + '\', this.id);">');
document.writeln('              <option value="">[Style]</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<p>">Paragraph &lt;p&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<h1>">Heading 1 &lt;h1&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<h2>">Heading 2 &lt;h2&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<h3>">Heading 3 &lt;h3&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<h4>">Heading 4 &lt;h4&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<h5>">Heading 5 &lt;h5&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<h6>">Heading 6 &lt;h6&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<address>">Address &lt;ADDR&gt </option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="<pre>">Formatted &lt;pre&gt;</option>');
document.writeln('          </select>');
document.writeln('      </td>');
document.writeln('      <td>');
document.writeln('          <select id="fontname_' + rte + '" onchange="selectFont(\'' + rte + '\', this.id)">');
document.writeln('              <option value="Font" selected>[Font]</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Arial</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="Courier New, Courier, mono">Courier New</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="Times New Roman, Times, serif">Times New Roman</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Verdana</option>');
document.writeln('          </select>');
document.writeln('      </td>');
document.writeln('      <td>');
document.writeln('          <select unselectable="on" id="fontsize_' + rte + '" onchange="selectFont(\'' + rte + '\', this.id);">');
document.writeln('              <option value="Size">[Size]</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="1">1</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="2">2</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="3">3</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="4">4</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="5">5</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="6">6</option>');
document.writeln('              <option value="7">7</option>');
document.writeln('          </select>');
document.writeln('      </td>');
document.writeln('      <td width="100%">');
document.writeln('      </td>');
document.writeln('  </tr>');
document.writeln('</table>');
document.writeln('<table class="rteBack" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Buttons2_' + rte + '" width="' + tablewidth + '">');
document.writeln('  <tr>');
document.writeln('      <td><img id="bold" class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'bold.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Bold" title="Bold" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'bold\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'italic.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Italic" title="Italic" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'italic\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'underline.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Underline" title="Underline" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'underline\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'left_just.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Align Left" title="Align Left" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'justifyleft\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'centre.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Center" title="Center" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'justifycenter\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'right_just.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Align Right" title="Align Right" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'justifyright\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'justifyfull.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Justify Full" title="Justify Full" onclick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'justifyfull\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'hr.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Horizontal Rule" title="Horizontal Rule" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'inserthorizontalrule\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'numbered_list.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Ordered List" title="Ordered List" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'insertorderedlist\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'list.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Unordered List" title="Unordered List" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'insertunorderedlist\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'outdent.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Outdent" title="Outdent" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'outdent\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'indent.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Indent" title="Indent" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'indent\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><div id="forecolor_' + rte + '"><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'textcolor.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Text Color" title="Text Color" onClick="dlgColorPalette(\'' + rte + '\', \'forecolor\', \'\')"></div></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><div id="hilitecolor_' + rte + '"><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'bgcolor.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Background Color" title="Background Color" onClick="dlgColorPalette(\'' + rte + '\', \'hilitecolor\', \'\')"></div></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'hyperlink.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Insert Link" title="Insert Link" onClick="insertLink(\'' + rte + '\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'image.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Add Image" title="Add Image" onClick="addImage(\'' + rte + '\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td><div id="table_' + rte + '"><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'insert_table.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Insert Table" title="Insert Table" onClick="dlgInsertTable(\'' + rte + '\', \'table\', \'\')"></div></td>');
if (isIE) {
document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'spellcheck.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Spell Check" title="Spell Check" onClick="checkspell()"></td>');
}
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'cut.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Cut" title="Cut" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'cut\')"></td>');
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'copy.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Copy" title="Copy" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'copy\')"></td>');
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'paste.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Paste" title="Paste" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'paste\')"></td>');
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteVertSep" src="' + imagesPath + 'blackdot.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0" alt=""></td>');
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'undo.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Undo" title="Undo" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'undo\')"></td>');
//      document.writeln('      <td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'redo.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Redo" title="Redo" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'redo\')"></td>');
document.writeln('      <td width="100%"></td>');
document.writeln('  </tr>');
document.writeln('</table>');
}
document.writeln('<iframe id="' + rte + '" name="' + rte + '" width="' + width + 'px" height="' + height + 'px" src="' + includesPath + 'blank.htm"></iframe>');
if (!readOnly) document.writeln('<br /><input type="checkbox" id="chkSrc' + rte + '" onclick="toggleHTMLSrc(\'' + rte + '\');" />&nbsp;View Source');
document.writeln('<iframe width="154" height="104" id="cp' + rte + '" src="' + includesPath + 'palette.htm" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="visibility:hidden; position: absolute;"></iframe>');
document.writeln('<input type="hidden" id="hdn' + rte + '" name="' + rte + '" value="">');
document.writeln('</div>');
document.getElementById('hdn' + rte).value = html;
enableDesignMode(rte, html, readOnly);
} else {
if (!readOnly) {
document.writeln('<textarea name="' + rte + '" id="' + rte + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;">' + html + '</textarea>');
} else {
document.writeln('<textarea name="' + rte + '" id="' + rte + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;" readonly>' + html + '</textarea>');
}
}
}

function enableDesignMode(rte, html, readOnly) {
var frameHtml = "<html id=\"" + rte + "\">\n";
frameHtml += "<head>\n";
//to reference your stylesheet, set href property below to your stylesheet path and uncomment
if (cssFile.length > 0) {
frameHtml += "<link media=\"all\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" + cssFile + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n";
} else {
frameHtml += "<style>\n";
frameHtml += "body {\n";
frameHtml += "  background: #FFFFFF;\n";
frameHtml += "  margin: 0px;\n";
frameHtml += "  padding: 0px;\n";
frameHtml += "}\n";
frameHtml += "</style>\n";
}
frameHtml += "</head>\n";
frameHtml += "<body>\n";
frameHtml += html + "\n";
frameHtml += "</body>\n";
frameHtml += "</html>";
if (document.all) {
var oRTE = frames[rte].document;
oRTE.open();
oRTE.write(frameHtml);
oRTE.close();
if (!readOnly) oRTE.designMode = "On";
} else {
try {
if (!readOnly) document.getElementById(rte).contentDocument.designMode = "on";
try {
var oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow.document;
oRTE.open();
oRTE.write(frameHtml);
oRTE.close();
if (isGecko && !readOnly) {
//attach a keyboard handler for gecko browsers to make keyboard shortcuts work
oRTE.addEventListener("keypress", kb_handler, true);
}
} catch (e) {
alert("Error preloading content.");
}
} catch (e) {
//gecko may take some time to enable design mode.
//Keep looping until able to set.
if (isGecko) {
setTimeout("enableDesignMode('" + rte + "', '" + html + "', " + readOnly + ");", 10);
} else {
return false;
}
}
}
}

function updateRTEs() {
var vRTEs = allRTEs.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < vRTEs.length; i++) {
updateRTE(vRTEs[i]);
}
}

function updateRTE(rte) {
if (!isRichText) return;
//set message value
var oHdnMessage = document.getElementById('hdn' + rte);
var oRTE = document.getElementById(rte);
var readOnly = false;
//check for readOnly mode
if (document.all) {
if (frames[rte].document.designMode != "On") readOnly = true;
} else {
if (document.getElementById(rte).contentDocument.designMode != "on") readOnly = true;
}

if (isRichText && !readOnly) {
//if viewing source, switch back to design view
if (document.getElementById("chkSrc" + rte).checked) {
document.getElementById("chkSrc" + rte).checked = false;
toggleHTMLSrc(rte);
}
if (oHdnMessage.value == null) oHdnMessage.value = "";
if (document.all) {
oHdnMessage.value = frames[rte].document.body.innerHTML;
} else {
oHdnMessage.value = oRTE.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
//if there is no content (other than formatting) set value to nothing
if (stripHTML(oHdnMessage.value.replace("&nbsp;", " ")) == "" 
&& oHdnMessage.value.toLowerCase().search("<hr") == -1
&& oHdnMessage.value.toLowerCase().search("<img") == -1) oHdnMessage.value = "";
//fix for gecko
if (escape(oHdnMessage.value) == "%3Cbr%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A") oHdnMessage.value = "";
}
}

function rteCommand(rte, command, option) {
//function to perform command
var oRTE;
if (document.all) {
oRTE = frames[rte];
} else {
oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow;
}
try {
oRTE.focus();
oRTE.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
oRTE.focus();
} catch (e) {
//  alert(e);
//  setTimeout("rteCommand('" + rte + "', '" + command + "', '" + option + "');", 10);
}
}

function toggleHTMLSrc(rte) {
//contributed by Bob Hutzel (thanks Bob!)
var oRTE;
if (document.all) {
oRTE = frames[rte].document;
} else {
oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow.document;
}   
if (document.getElementById("chkSrc" + rte).checked) {
showHideElement("Buttons1_" + rte, "hide");
showHideElement("Buttons2_" + rte, "hide");
if (document.all) {
oRTE.body.innerText = oRTE.body.innerHTML;
} else {
var htmlSrc = oRTE.createTextNode(oRTE.body.innerHTML);
oRTE.body.innerHTML = "";
oRTE.body.appendChild(htmlSrc);
}
} else {
showHideElement("Buttons1_" + rte, "show");
showHideElement("Buttons2_" + rte, "show");
if (document.all) {
//fix for IE
var output = escape(oRTE.body.innerText);
output = output.replace("%3CP%3E%0D%0A%3CHR%3E", "%3CHR%3E");
output = output.replace("%3CHR%3E%0D%0A%3C/P%3E", "%3CHR%3E");
oRTE.body.innerHTML = unescape(output);
} else {
var htmlSrc = oRTE.body.ownerDocument.createRange();
htmlSrc.selectNodeContents(oRTE.body);
oRTE.body.innerHTML = htmlSrc.toString();
}
}
}

function dlgColorPalette(rte, command) {
//function to display or hide color palettes
setRange(rte);

//get dialog position
var oDialog = document.getElementById('cp' + rte);
var buttonElement = document.getElementById(command + '_' + rte);
var iLeftPos = getOffsetLeft(buttonElement);
var iTopPos = getOffsetTop(buttonElement) + (buttonElement.offsetHeight + 4);
oDialog.style.left = (iLeftPos) + "px";
oDialog.style.top = (iTopPos) + "px";

if ((command == parent.command) && (rte == currentRTE)) {
//if current command dialog is currently open, close it
if (oDialog.style.visibility == "hidden") {
showHideElement(oDialog, 'show');
} else {
showHideElement(oDialog, 'hide');
}
} else {
//if opening a new dialog, close all others
var vRTEs = allRTEs.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < vRTEs.length; i++) {
showHideElement('cp' + vRTEs[i], 'hide');
}
showHideElement(oDialog, 'show');
}

//save current values
parent.command = command;
currentRTE = rte;
}

function dlgInsertTable(rte, command) {
//function to open/close insert table dialog
//save current values
setRange(rte);
parent.command = command;
currentRTE = rte;
var windowOptions = 'history=no,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=360,height=200';
window.open(includesPath + 'insert_table.htm', 'InsertTable', windowOptions);
}

function insertLink(rte) {
//function to insert link
var szURL = prompt("Enter a URL:", "");
try {
//ignore error for blank urls
rteCommand(rte, "Unlink", null);
rteCommand(rte, "CreateLink", szURL);
} catch (e) {
//do nothing
}
}

function setColor(color) {
//function to set color
var rte = currentRTE;
var parentCommand = parent.command;

if (document.all) {
//retrieve selected range
var sel = frames[rte].document.selection; 
if (parentCommand == "hilitecolor") parentCommand = "backcolor";
if (sel != null) {
var newRng = sel.createRange();
newRng = rng;
newRng.select();
}
}

rteCommand(rte, parentCommand, color);
showHideElement('cp' + rte, "hide");
}

function addImage(rte) {
//function to add image
imagePath = prompt('Enter Image URL:', 'http://');              
if ((imagePath != null) && (imagePath != "")) {
rteCommand(rte, 'InsertImage', imagePath);
}
}

// Ernst de Moor: Fix the amount of digging parents up, in case the RTE editor itself is displayed in a div.
// KJR 11/12/2004 Changed to position palette based on parent div, so palette will always appear in proper location regardless of nested divs
function getOffsetTop(elm) {
var mOffsetTop = elm.offsetTop;
var mOffsetParent = elm.offsetParent;
var parents_up = 2; //the positioning div is 2 elements up the tree

while(parents_up > 0) {
mOffsetTop += mOffsetParent.offsetTop;
mOffsetParent = mOffsetParent.offsetParent;
parents_up--;
}

return mOffsetTop;
}

// Ernst de Moor: Fix the amount of digging parents up, in case the RTE editor itself is displayed in a div.
// KJR 11/12/2004 Changed to position palette based on parent div, so palette will always appear in proper location regardless of nested divs
function getOffsetLeft(elm) {
var mOffsetLeft = elm.offsetLeft;
var mOffsetParent = elm.offsetParent;
var parents_up = 2;

while(parents_up > 0) {
mOffsetLeft += mOffsetParent.offsetLeft;
mOffsetParent = mOffsetParent.offsetParent;
parents_up--;
}

return mOffsetLeft;
}

function selectFont(rte, selectname) {
//function to handle font changes
var idx = document.getElementById(selectname).selectedIndex;
// First one is always a label
if (idx != 0) {
var selected = document.getElementById(selectname).options[idx].value;
var cmd = selectname.replace('_' + rte, '');
rteCommand(rte, cmd, selected);
document.getElementById(selectname).selectedIndex = 0;
}
}

function kb_handler(evt) {
var rte = evt.target.id;

//contributed by Anti Veeranna (thanks Anti!)
if (evt.ctrlKey) {
var key = String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode).toLowerCase();
var cmd = '';
switch (key) {
case 'b': cmd = "bold"; break;
case 'i': cmd = "italic"; break;
case 'u': cmd = "underline"; break;
};

if (cmd) {
rteCommand(rte, cmd, null);

// stop the event bubble
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
}
}
}

function insertHTML(html) {
//function to add HTML -- thanks dannyuk1982
var rte = currentRTE;

var oRTE;
if (document.all) {
oRTE = frames[rte];
} else {
oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow;
}

oRTE.focus();
if (document.all) {
oRTE.document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
} else {
oRTE.document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
}
}

function showHideElement(element, showHide) {
//function to show or hide elements
//element variable can be string or object
if (document.getElementById(element)) {
element = document.getElementById(element);
}

if (showHide == "show") {
element.style.visibility = "visible";
} else if (showHide == "hide") {
element.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
}

function setRange(rte) {
//function to store range of current selection
var oRTE;
if (document.all) {
oRTE = frames[rte];
var selection = oRTE.document.selection; 
if (selection != null) rng = selection.createRange();
} else {
oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow;
var selection = oRTE.getSelection();
rng = selection.getRangeAt(selection.rangeCount - 1).cloneRange();
}
}

function stripHTML(oldString) {
//function to strip all html
var newString = oldString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

//replace carriage returns and line feeds
newString = newString.replace(/\r\n/g," ");
newString = newString.replace(/\n/g," ");
newString = newString.replace(/\r/g," ");

//trim string
newString = trim(newString);

return newString;
}

function trim(inputString) {
// Removes leading and trailing spaces from the passed string. Also removes
// consecutive spaces and replaces it with one space. If something besides
// a string is passed in (null, custom object, etc.) then return the input.
if (typeof inputString != "string") return inputString;
var retValue = inputString;
var ch = retValue.substring(0, 1);

while (ch == " ") { // Check for spaces at the beginning of the string
retValue = retValue.substring(1, retValue.length);
ch = retValue.substring(0, 1);
}
ch = retValue.substring(retValue.length - 1, retValue.length);

while (ch == " ") { // Check for spaces at the end of the string
retValue = retValue.substring(0, retValue.length - 1);
ch = retValue.substring(retValue.length - 1, retValue.length);
}

// Note that there are two spaces in the string - look for multiple spaces within the string
while (retValue.indexOf("  ") != -1) {
// Again, there are two spaces in each of the strings
retValue = retValue.substring(0, retValue.indexOf("  ")) + retValue.substring(retValue.indexOf("  ") + 1, retValue.length);
```

}
    return retValue; // Return the trimmed string back to the user
    }

```
//*****************
//IE-Only Functions
//*****************
function checkspell() {
//function to perform spell check
try {
var tmpis = new ActiveXObject("ieSpell.ieSpellExtension");
tmpis.CheckAllLinkedDocuments(document);
}
catch(exception) {
if(exception.number==-2146827859) {
if (confirm("ieSpell not detected.  Click Ok to go to download page."))
window.open("http://www.iespell.com/download.php","DownLoad");
} else {
alert("Error Loading ieSpell: Exception " + exception.number);
}
}
}

function raiseButton(e) {
//IE-Only Function
var el = window.event.srcElement;

className = el.className;
if (className == 'rteImage' || className == 'rteImageLowered') {
el.className = 'rteImageRaised';
}
}

function normalButton(e) {
//IE-Only Function
var el = window.event.srcElement;

className = el.className;
if (className == 'rteImageRaised' || className == 'rteImageLowered') {
el.className = 'rteImage';
}
}

function lowerButton(e) {
//IE-Only Function
var el = window.event.srcElement;

className = el.className;
if (className == 'rteImage' || className == 'rteImageRaised') {
el.className = 'rteImageLowered';
}
}
```

Comment: There is so little information that it shocks me, include your html, js and maybe even the css

Comment: Hard to tell from your brief description. Maybe, you're still referencing the local paths to the thumbnails on your uploaded version?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because Menucool requires that you purchase a license.  They will then give you a code that you insert in the JS file:

license: "mylicense"